# Do hotlinked images follow 301 redirects?

Tags: 301-redirect

Site `www.example.com` hotlinks an image from site `www.example-photos.com` (with permission).

Site `www.example-photos.com` redirects its images to a new domain, `www.photo-center.com`.

Will the `<img src="">` tag on site `www.example.com` follow the 301 redirects to `www.example-photos.com` so that when a page is viewed on `www.example.com` the image will still be displayed?

Or would `www.example.com` need to update its `<img>` tag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, browsers will follow 301 redirects on externally linked images in the same way they would for any other HTTP request.